# Matlab rgb2gray() undefined function error

Tags: matlab, licensing

Unfortunately, against all resistance, I am again forced to use Matlab. I'm attempting to use some code that I know for a fact ran a few months earlier.

Here is my code:

```
colour_image = imread(filename);
grey_image = rgb2gray(colour_image);
```

Here is my error:

```
Undefined function 'rgb2gray' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

Here is the documentation of rgb2gray:

```
% If the input is an RGB image, it can be uint8, uint16, double, or
% single.
```

So the function allows uint8 arguments, but gives me an error when given uint8 arguments. Why?

I googled around and was led to this link:

```
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4B6E5E/
```

Okay lets make sure I have the correct toolbox (even though I know its there)

I typed: ver

```
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 8.0        (R2012a)
```

Okay great, I have the correct toolbox, licensed and all.

I typed: which -all rgb2gray

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\images\images\rgb2gray.m  % Has no license available
```

Okay, so even though I have the correct licensed toolbox, this specific function is not licensed.... hmmm okay?

So lets try this "license checkout" thing, but first I have to find my licenses keyname. To find the license key name, I need to look at the INCREMENT lines in my license file...great.

So I go to:

```
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-63ZIR6/index.html
```

Hmmm since this is over a network and I'm on a client machine I have a "network.lic", I open it up to find my INCREMENT line and of course its not there!

```
If your license.dat file has no INCREMENT lines, refer to your license administrator for these INCREMENT lines.
```

Can someone please put me out of my misery?

EDIT: So after running the license check i get:

```
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -101
```

According to the site:

```
This error message indicates that the license administrator has reserved all the licenses of the product you are trying to use for other users.
```

And since my admin is on leave, I'm going to try convince my supervisor to let me switch to using a C/C++ image processing library. Thanks for the help.

Comment: put all your code here please

Comment: what is the dimension of your `colour_image` matrix ? it needs to be 3D (`m` x `n` x `3`) for the rgb components

Comment: That is all my code. The image is 512x512x3 uint8.

Comment: Did you "refer to your license administrator"? Seems like the place to start.

Comment: If that's referring to the admin of the lab I'm working in, he is on medical leave...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short name after INCREMENT for Image Processing Toolbox in a license file is:

> Image_Toolbox

**UPDATED:**

Alternatively, maybe this can help you: [How do I convert my RGB image to grayscale without using the Image Processing Toolbox?](http://mathworks.ch/support/solutions/en/data/1-1ASCU)

Comment: Now after I check I get "Licensing error: -101" so apparently "the license administrator has reserved all the licenses of the product you are trying to use for other users". So I guess I'm SOL.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using just a flat average of the RGB components, I completely overlooked weighting the channels separately!